# Facebook messenger for website working in Firefox, not Chrome

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, nginx, facebook-javascript-sdk

This might be trivial but I'm trying to set up Facebook messenger for websites as it's available through pages. It loads perfectly fine on Firefox (*as below*)

[image: fb messenger]

When it comes to loading it on Chrome, I'm greeted by the following error:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/plugins/customerchat.php?app_id=226382507935447&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FNh1oH0K63yz.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df3ee1b33e9fa724%26domain%3Dwww.MYWEBSITE.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.MYWEBSITE.com%252Ffa7870694c0fac%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=0&locale=en_US&page_id=1323494501052770&sdk=joey' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://www.facebook.com".
```

I've done my fair share of research around this and run through adding/removing my domain names from the whitelist, turning off/modifying my `'Content-Security-Policy` header & `X-Frame-Options` headers, but to no avail.

I currently have my `X-Frame-Options` header set to: `SAMEORIGIN` and my `Content-Security-Policy` to:

```
default-src 'self'; 
frame-src 'self' https://*.facebook.com https://*.googleapis.com; 
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://cdn.adaptivedigital.io https://*.googleapis.com https://*.gstatic.com https://*.facebook.net https://*.facebook.com *.google-analytics.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' http://cdn.adaptivedigital.io https://*.googleapis.com; 
img-src 'self' http://cdn.adaptivedigital.io https://*.google-analytics.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.facebook.net https://*.googleapis.com https://*.gstatic.com; 
font-src 'self' http://cdn.adaptivedigital.io https://*.googleapis.com https://*.gstatic.com; 
object-src 'none'
```

I've been stuck on this for the last 4 hours, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Btw,

Chrome Version: `Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it. Turns out I had the following set;

```
add_header Referrer-Policy 'no-referrer';
```

Which in turn broke the Facebook messenger plugin (*still weird that it only happened in Chrome*).

I ended up setting it to;

```
add_header Referrer-Policy 'origin';
```

Comment: Hi Darren, I have same issue. Where did you set the add_header code as I am taking the JS / HTML code generated by FB from page settings. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @MrMegamind I put it in my web server's (nginx) server block. What web server are you using if you know?

Comment: I have APACHE serving my website. This is confusing. The widget embeds on client side using JS and calls the FB server. How can anything fix the issue by changing in our server ! while it has nothing to do with the embed